# Certain private group sites not appearing in search results

Tags: search, office-365

We use the SharePoint Search REST APIs to search for all websites in our tenant, but there are a few private group sites that do not appear in the search results. They also does not appear if we use the Graph API (`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=*`).

Our app has daemon permissions so I think the groups' ownerships and memberships shouldn't matter.

How do I make them show up in the search results? Is this a bug on Microsoft's side?

What we tried:

1. Turn on the sites' "Allow this site to appear in Search results" option
2. Follow the instructions in https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/crawl-site-content to re-crawl the website
3. Wait for 24 hours
4. Search with the search API:

```
https://site-url/_api/Search/Query?QueryText='contentclass:STS_Site contentclass:STS_Web'&EnableStemming=false&TrimDuplicates=false
```